# ¿Qué hacen las instrucciones delegate e invoke en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando entender la siguiente parte de este código...

```cs
public void actualizarUI(string s) {
    Func<int> del = delegate() {
        txttcpResultados.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
        return 0;
    };

    Invoke(del);
}
```

La línea del `Func<int> del = delegate ()` y la de `Invoke(del);`, ¿qué hace exactamente? Si se genera una función con un parámetro de entrada tipo *string* y no se pone nada de eso, la función funcionaría igualmente.

¿Qué beneficios aporta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La instrucción

```
Func<int> del = delegate ()
{
   txttcpResultados.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
   return 0;
};
```

Lo que hace es declarar una variable `del` cuyo valor es una función que no recibe ningún parámetro y devuelve un valor entero.

Esto puede resultar útil en muchos casos, principalmente cuando quieres pasar un método o función como argumento a otro método. Casos típicos del uso de delegados pueden ser los controladores de eventos de controles en Windows Forms o una función de ordenación que se pasa a un método de una lista.

En los métodos de manejos de listas puedes encontrar muchos ejemplos ([Enumerable.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx))

La instrucción

```
Invoke(del);
```

Lo que está haciendo es llamar al método `Invoke` del objeto en el que se ejecuta el método, por el código supongo que será un `Form` de Windows Forms.

Lo que hace el método `Invoke` es ejecutar el delegado `del` en el mismo subproceso en el que se está ejecutando la ventana en la que está contenido el control. Esto puede resultar muy práctico en escenarios multihilo, en el que el código puede estar ejecutándose en un hilo diferente pero las instrucciones de actualización del interfaz deben ejecutarse en el mismo subproceso que la ventana.

En cuanto a la última pregunta. Si el delegado tuviese un argumento de tipo `string` deberías pasárselo al llamar al método `Invoke`. De otro modo recibirás una excepción del tipo `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException`.

La llamada debería ser:

```
 Invoke(del, micadena);
```

Comment: existe una edición pendiente en tu respuesta, la cual es de un usuario con poca reputación. La rechacé porque no estoy seguro si realmente es algo de lo que deseabas expresar en tu respuesta. Pero, lo dejo a tu consideración. Igual si se acepta y no la deseas puedes revertir el cambio. :)